# Waiting for device token with parse Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am currently developing on Android and using Parse. My goal is to get the device Token and send it to a web service in order to register an install. 
I have this code :

```
installation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
       @Override
       public void done(ParseException e) {
       // Saved!
       if(e==null){
           String deviceToken = (String)installation.get("deviceToken");
           String objectId    = installation.getObjectId();
           Log.d("test","device token : "+deviceToken);
           Log.d("test","object id : "+objectId);
       }else{
           Log.d("test","error : "+e.getMessage());
       }
     }
});
```

`ObjectId` is fine but I am always getting `null` for the deviceToken. But on my `Parse.com` back-end the DeviceToken is here and well defined...

**So, what is the solution to avoid getting null and to send the right data ?**

I found nothing about my problem in the **parse documentation** or **Parse Android community**.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use following method to get current installation. and then device Id - In above code, the save call back is not returning you the saved object

```
String deviceToken = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("deviceToken");
String objectID = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getObjectId();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can get `installationID` and work with it:

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
String installationID = installation.getInstallationId();
```

because sometimes `deviceToken` is `null`
[image]